# “Gossip about gossip” protocols

Tags: network-programming, distributed-computing, consensus, hashgraph, hedera-hashgraph

Lately there is much rumor about the (patented) hashgraph consensus algorithm, which claims to have very good complexity measures. See the whitepaper:

https://swirlds.com/downloads/SWIRLDS-TR-2016-01.pdf

A central part of this appoach, is the so called "gossip about gossip" which uses a gossip protocol to spred the gossip history itself through the network. At least, if I'm not mistaken. This builds a data structure called the hashgraph.

On top of this, then runs a Byzantine fault tollerance algorithm, but that is of no concern for this question, which is:

Is the hashgraph-algorithm really the first who uses such a data structure, to gossip about gossip, or are there previous/other approaches, too? Couldn't find anything, though.

Edit: I have problems finding the right Tags. Maybe someone could elaborate on this?

Answer (score 2):

I think that all the voting algorithms are in a way doing gossip about gossip. It is not a revolution, you just share more about what you know and also how do you know it.

I suppose, Gossip about gossip is just a pitch. The real contribution is the math proofs on virtual voting based on the notion of seeing.

Comment: I think the very same thing. Even the cryptographic algorithm in the original paper on Byzantine generals uses gossip over gossip to achieve agreement. However Hashgraphs patent got approval.

Answer (score 1):

It is core of the patent - invention by Leemon Baird [paper 16 Bird](http://leemon.com/papers/2016b.pdf), [patent](https://patents.google.com/?inventor=Leemon%20C.%20Baird%2C%20III)

Answer (score 1):

Gossip about gossip simply means send a node what other nodes have gossiped about.

- Node a and node b gossiped and shared some information.
- Then node c gossiped with node a in which node a shared what did it gossip about with node b.
- So now node c knows what node b already knows and can avoid sending that to him thereby saving bandwidth.